# Pandas rolling window appears to introduce offset to rolled data

Tags: python, pandas, scientific-computing

I am looking to 'smooth' regularly-sampled 30-sec time series data using the pandas `rolling_window` function, with a window type other than `boxcar` - ideally `hamming`. However, so far all windows which I have tried to apply, over varying window lengths from 2 to 100, appear to offset the smoothed data to lower values, e.g.:
[image: Plot of raw data (light blue) and data run through <code>pd.rolling_window(data,2,'hamming')</code>]

Plot of raw data (light blue) and data run through `pd.rolling_window(data,2,'hamming')`.

Clearly, the quantity of offset varies through time.

This result isn't what I would expect - rather, I'd expect the filtered dataset to sit atop the raw one.

Any explanations of what might be happening here would be great.

Comment: Why do you specifically want to use `hamming`? Is it appropriate for your dataset?

Comment: Ah - I think I've accidentally crossed 'hamming' and 'hanning' over in my mind. 'Hanning' doesn't appear as an option so I'll have to give further thought to this, but the critical thing is that I've tried a variety of filters, including `triang` which would be appropriate, and they all (apart from `boxcar`) yield the same 'offset' series.

Comment: I know nothing about signal processing, but in econometrics you need to be careful with non-stationary time series. Maybe try detrending first or have a look at [statsmodels' time series filters](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/tsa.html#other-time-series-filters)

Comment: To verify correctness apply the rolling window on a step function. If there were an offset, it would show up

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by a step function?

Comment: A step function increases its output by a set amount per time.  It will produce a diagonal line.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `center=True` argument to rolling_window.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that ajt meant the *vertical* offset, not a horizontal one.