# Pandas rolling window function offsets data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, gaussian

I am attempting to use the Pandas rolling_window function, with win_type = 'gaussian' or win_type = 'general_gaussian'. I have a time-series dataset, indexed by datetime, and I need a smoothing function to reduce noise. I would like to avoid the boxcar, and instead use a Gaussian weighting. I have experimented with many ranges of window size and std (for gaussian), and window size, power, and width values (for general Gaussian), and I consistently get the same result: the smoothed output is offset lower than the original input data. This is the same issue that was asked but remains unanswered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21332896/pandas-rolling-window-appears-to-introduce-offset-to-rolled-data/27204561#27204561).

The specific line of code I am trying to use for this is:

```
dNorth_smooth = rolling_window(s, window=40, win_type='gaussian', std=30, center=True, freq='15S')
```

Where 's' is a single column of data in a datetime-indexed Pandas dataframe. In this case, 's' is position in meters, at 15 second time intervals. So, my window size is 40 lines, or 40*15 = 600 sec = 10 min. It is not clear what exactly the std argument refers to, but I assume this is in the frequency domain, and would be some value smaller than the window size, controlling the shape of the Gaussian curve (regardless, I have experimented with many std values; if std is very large, then no offset occurs, but this is because the Gaussian curve becomes so wide compared to the window, that you are essentially using a boxcar). The 'center' and 'freq' arguments do not appear to change output either way. Other optional arguments also seem irrelevant.

Once I have higher reputation I can post a plot to help explain. But see the plot at the linked question above, as this is the exact same problem I have. Also to note: the boxcar window (which is equivalent to rolling_mean) does *not* have this offset problem. It does, however, seem to exist with all other window weighting functions (triang, blackman, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there has been no specific Pandas solution posted for this question (or the similar linked question), I am posting a solution using standard numpy and scipy functions. This will produce a smoothed curve using gaussian weighting, and works for any magnitude data (does not have offset issues).

```
def smooth_gaussian(data,window,std):
  g = sp.signal.gaussian(window,std,sym=True)
  con = np.convolve(g/g.sum(),data,mode='valid')
  con_shift = np.r_[np.full((window*0.5),np.nan),con,np.full((window*0.5),np.nan)]
  return con_shift
```

The resulting dataset is shorter than the input dataset by the length of the window, as the first and last "smoothed" data points occur at (window * 0.5) from either end. The returned variable `con_shift` accounts for this, and centers the smoothed data with respect to the input data, so that they are the same length and can be plotted together. `window` argument is the size of the moving window, and `std` is the standard deviation, controlling the shape of the Gaussian curve (I set mine to 0.1 * window). Note that for `con_shift` to be symmetric, window size must be an odd integer.